# Wordpress saving customization when updating plugin

Tags: wordpress, customization, updating, contact-form-7

I've made some changes to the contact form 7 plugin for wordpress in the scripts.js file.

They are regarding
`$.fn.wpcf7InitForm -> beforeSubmit`
`$.fn.wpcf7AjaxLoader -> var loader`
`$.fn.wpcf7NotValidTip` with focus coding

What is the best practice for keeping these changes? Once I update the plugin it will overwrite everything I re-written.

From what I can tell, the only way would be to save my new scripts.js file in e.g. [my theme folder]->assets->js->wpcf7->scripts.js Then deregister the original file and register my new one and enqueue it in my themes functions.php.

Is there a better way? Is there a way to affect just the parts I've changed, or do I have to register the entire new scripts.js file (i.e. deregister original and register the new file VS. just appending what I've changed in a new file somehow)?

Comment: What I do on plugins is to keep a copy on my desktop, and when I update, I run a winmrege on it, to check what to do... So yeah, I do it manually, so you have to change as few things as possible... But maybe there is an other way to do it I'm not aware of...

Comment: Right, I save a copy of the file I've changed in my themes folder. But what I'm wondering is if there is a way to make this more smooth and not have to overwrite files in plugin folders every time I update (seeing as the changes I've made are mostly visually related).